# How to get back ubuntu-desktop?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, apt

I ran the command `sudo apt-get install sqlite`. Then some scripts ran on the command prompt, I don't know what happened, but a phrase from the last line was "uninstalled library" . Then I shoted down my system. Now when I am trying to login, it's showing `fail to start session` . Then I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and I came here , picture is tagged below. What commands should I run here to get Ubuntu desktop back?

[image]

Comment: Just edited, please see

Comment: check out `man dpkg`. I have a feeling you will find it interesting. Great explanation of how broken packages work behind the scenes and some shortcuts for fixing them as well.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by resolving dpkg: errors .Here is the link how I resolved it

[Python3 cannot be downloaded result, after $sudo apt --reinstall install python3 command.ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350655/python3-cannot-be-downloaded-result-after-sudo-apt-reinstall-install-python3?noredirect=1#comment2309200_1350655)

Then ran

```
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

But again it was showing unmet dependencies. Then I installed those dependencies one by one . It was a chain of dependencies,i had to go by each one, some were upgraded, some were downgraded, but finally installed. Then I ran

```
 sudo apt update
```

and again

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

And finally got a desktop to start a session.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing `ctrl+alt+F2` from the login screen should get you a tty terminal. From there, just run `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` from tty. If that doesn't fix it, run `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: After running those commands, output-                   `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
                  Ubuntu-desktop :  Depends: gdm3 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ghostscript-x but it is not going to be installed
Depends: gnome-shell but it is ...
Depends: gstreamer1.0-packagekit but it is ..
Depends: nautilus but it is not goi....
Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not .....
Recommends: cups-bsd
Recommends: evince but ..
.........................
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`

Comment: Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and let me know the output.

Comment: After running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, Result-.   `....... 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded` `1 not fully installed or removed` `After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.` `Do you want to continue? [Y/N] y` `setting up python3-django (1:1.11.11-1ubuntu1)...` `file "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py".line 152``...... SyntaxError: Generator ......` `dpkg: error processing python3-django (--configure):` `installed python3-django package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1`

Comment: `Errors were encountered while processing: python3-django` `libdvd-pkg: package libdvdcss2-1.4.2-1 was removed,stop processing....` `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Then I tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` nothing changed in output . Then tried   `sudo apt-get --reinstall install python3` , Result- `Reinstallation of python is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.`And then, `the same dpkg error output`  python version is python3.7.5

Comment: No , I didn't  :(

Comment: You are still using apt-get. Try using only apt.

Comment: You should be using only apt, unless apt-get is specifically needed. You can think of apt-get as being sort of like the root user of the APT commands. In certain cases, it comes in handy, but 99% of the time it's just easier to break stuff. Ever since apt command was released, apt-get is only for special situations

Comment: Ok, I did run the command `sudo apt --reinstall install python3` and still getting same error .

Comment: My terminal is showing `~bash: ./rslsync: No such file or directory.  0 packages can be updated `, is it restricting python3 download?  I have no idea, please answer.