# Python3 cannot be downloaded result, after $sudo apt --reinstall install python3 command.ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, updates, python3, django

Whenever I try to update or upgrade anything,broken file

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py
```

is generating

```
SyntaxError:Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

How to upgrade this django ?

```
python 3.7.5
django 3.0
```

I tried to reinstall whole python3

```
$sudo apt --reinstall install python3
```

Result-

```
Python3 cannot be downloaded
```

How to fix this problem? I can't get into desktop. `fail to start session` .Running everything from terminal.

Comment: How did you install Django and Python to begin with?  If you are using PIP to install Django it would just work, but your Django and Python don't seem to be the system python versions that are installed.  Do you have any PPAs?  Did you replace system Python with a newer version?  (Python 3.6 is the default on 18.04 I believe)

Comment: Ok, so there is the problem? System is not mine, I can't say the history.      Thanks for the reply.

Comment: How can I check for PPA now? And if there is one, can I use that to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after so long days I touched my defected system again and solved the issue.
I had to purge the broken package python3-django. But I didn't directly ran the command to remove the package, because I didn't want any unknown consequences further. Then thankfully I got to know about command

```
 `sudo apt-get --simulate remove python3-django'
```

This command shows the aftermath of removing the package. I ran the command, and Shaw only python3-django was going to be removed. So I proceeded and ran

```
'sudo apt-get remove python3-django`
```

Then ran

```
         `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
```

and it worked like a charm. Then I checked python version and django version and it was showing .